# How to list modified files?

Tags: php, arrays, linux, windows, cron

I'm developing a security Saas and I need to create a script that constantly crawls all public files on the server and alerts my database when a file is modified.

It must work on Windows/Linux.

What language, library or script should I use?

Thank you for your precious advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you tagged your question with PHP I suggest you using the PHP language^^

Because you said it should work cross platform you can't use filemtime.

I would suggest you to create a hash database (recursively!), you could use `md5_file` [Doc](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.md5-file.php)  for that.

In your cron job you crawl recursively again and compare the file hashes, if a hash changed the file changed after last check.

Comment: Note: There are also alternative hashing algorithms like sha1 etc.

Comment: Thanks.
Is there a way to activate cron job on the clients website without asking them to manually create it on cPanel?

Comment: cPanel is a webhosting administration tool, isnt it? You can create and start/stop Cronjobs for example using shell execute, but I think shell execute will be blocked on standard web hosting, on a VPS or Root Server you could use shell execute with the corresponding command.

Comment: Yes, you are right. 
Unfortunately, I think my clients use a shared hosting plan, so they have a lot of restrictions.

I thought there was a way to autorun the script through itself or .htaccess, but if it is not possible, I'll explain them how to create a cronjob on cPanel.

Comment: You could also ask them to upgrade to a VPS which has more power, depends on the amount of files you want to "watch" but on a specific amount and size of files I think a standard shared hosting doesn't fit the needs anymore. (Sure a VPS has to be secured and configured, but there are also Providers who preconfigure their servers and provide easy to use Admin Panels).

Beside this, don't forget to accept my answer, if it helped you (What I hope)